# DAX Power Pivot Building a Cash Flow Statement (indirect method)

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

Here is the current file for this question ([download from OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArAKssDW3T7wnIMQkg9cKf99VMfjAg))

I have the following data model:

[image]

This is the sample data in each table:

[image]

I have this DAX measure to calculate the running sum and get the subtotals for the income statement:

```
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( DIM_IncStatement[Label] );
    CALCULATE (
        [Total Value];
        ALL ( DIM_IncStatement );
        DIM_IncStatement[Code] < VALUES ( DIM_IncStatement[Code] )
    )
)
```

And this one for the operational profit:

```
=
CALCULATE (
    [Subtotal Income Statement];
    ALL ( DIM_IncStatement[Level1] );
    FILTER ( DIM_IncStatement; DIM_IncStatement[Code] = 9 )
)
```

Currently the pivot table for the income statement looks like this:

[image]

As the cash flow statement if built upon some information from the income statement, I need to get the information and put it in the corresponding rows.

This is the basic structure of the cash flow statement:

[image]

QUESTION:

What's the DAX measure to get the "Operational profit", "Cost depreciation",   "Expense depreciation", and finally the EBITDA (which is the sum of the previous) in place in the cash flow report?

[image]

I'have tried this for the operational profit, but after adding the measure, then pivot table gets empty:

```
=
CALCULATE (
    [Operational profit];
    ALL ( DIM_Cash_Flow );
    FILTER ( DIM_Cash_Flow; DIM_Cash_Flow[Report code] = "OP" )
)
```

If anybody can give a hint, I'd really appreciate it...being trying for hours!